# WordPress - Overwriting a Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a theme that extends the Visual Composer plugin with a slider on the front page. The slider will show five testimonials from five different customers. I want to add the featured image of each testimonial as the thumbnail in the slider.

Here's the shortened code from the parent theme:

```
function jo_customers_testimonials_slider( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, "widget_title" => __('What Are People Saying', 'jo'), 'text_color' => "#000" ), $atts ) );
    $content = "";
    $loopArgs = array( "post_type" => "customers", "posts_per_page" => $limit, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 );

    $postsLoop = new WP_Query( $loopArgs );
    $content = "";

    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider' );
```

My functions.php file:

```
function jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, "widget_title" => __('What Are People Saying', 'jo'), 'text_color' => "#000" ), $atts ) );
    $content = "";
    $loopArgs = array( "post_type" => "customers", "posts_per_page" => $limit, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 );

    $postsLoop = new WP_Query( $loopArgs );
    $content = "";

    $content .= '...';
    $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' );
    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail' );
```

In theory, the function from my functions.php file should overwrite the shortcode from the parent theme. But nothing seems to happen when I use this code. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Tried this code, but it still won't work.

```
function wpa_add_child_shortcodes(){
remove_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider');
    add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );
```

Also changed 

`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` to 

`add_action( 'init', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );`

, but no difference in the outcome.

**Edit 2 (With Solution):**

Changing `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` to `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` solved it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you need to call [remove_shortcode();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode) like this:

```php
remove_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider');`
```

Before you add your new shortcode with the same name to "overwrite" it.

You'll also need to call it after the parent theme has run so we fire on an action hook called [wp_loaded](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded).

```php
function overwrite_shortcode() {

    function jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail($atts) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array('limit' => 5, "widget_title" => __('What Are People Saying', 'jo'), 'text_color' => "#000"), $atts));
        $content = "";
        $loopArgs = array("post_type" => "customers", "posts_per_page" => $limit, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1);

        $postsLoop = new WP_Query($loopArgs);
        $content = "";

        $content .= '...';
        $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
        $content .= '...';
        $content .= '...';

        wp_reset_query();
        return $content;
    }

    remove_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider');
    add_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail');
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'overwrite_shortcode');
```

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work since the functions.php file gets called before the parent's theme function files.

Comment: have you tried doing something like this function shortcode_cleaner() {
    remove_shortcode(); 
    add_shortcode( );
}
add_action( 'init', 'shortcode_cleaner' ); that in theory should register your short code first and prevent his from overwriting it.

Comment: @Daniel you've got a stubborn one then... Have you attempted doing my last suggestion but instead of on init doing it on the after_setup_theme hook? or if your attempting to do it after his is registered try the wp_loaded hook

Comment: `after_setup_theme` doesn't work either. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Daniel what about the wp_loaded hook? and sorry for just throwing guesses out i don't have any child themes to test on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45740/discussion-between-clark-t-and-daniel)

Answer (score 5):

You have to write this code in your Child Theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'calling_child_theme_setup' );

function calling_child_theme_setup() {
   remove_shortcode( 'parent_shortcode_function' );
   add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'child_shortcode_function' );
}

function child_shortcode_function( $atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'img'  => '',
        'cat'  => '',
        'capt' => '',
        'link' => ''
    ), $atts );

//YOUR OWN CODE HERE

    $imgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $atts['img'], 'delicious-gallery' );

    $imgFull = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $atts['img'], 'full' );



    $b = '<div class="screen-item" data-groups=\'["'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $atts["cat"])).'", "all"]\'>'.

        '<a href="'.$atts["link"].'" data-title="'.$atts["capt"].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$imgSrc[0].'" alt="SCREEN" class="screenImg" /></a>'.

        '<span>'.$atts["capt"].'</span>'.

    '</div>';

//YOUR OWN CODE HERE

    return $b;
}
```